# Printed date on PDF generated by ABCpdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, pdf-generation, abcpdf

I generate PDFs from HTML with ABCpdf (.Net, version 9). When the PDF gets printed (which can be many days after it is generated), the date that it is being printed needs to be shown in the footer on the printed pages.

How can I make this happen? I guess it involves JavaScript embedded in the PDF, but not sure about the details.

Comment: It involves Javascript. But Javascript is not necessarily implemented on a PDF viewer (or printer), and even if implemented it may be disabled. Thus, unless the PDFs are only directed at a well controlled Installation base, that requirement cannot be fulfilled.

Comment: Fortunately, the PDFs will only be used within my organization. We can specify to users what PDF viewer to use. So this should not be a road block.

Comment: Here's a hint: http://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-print-current-date-printing-file-q35204.aspx#postComments35205 and this other one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351952/pdf-date-of-print